# Disable Submit button by clicking another button in AngularJS 1.3.15

Tags: html, angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have 2 buttons - Delete and Submit. Submit button is disabled initially. I am trying to **enable** Submit button whenever the user clicks on Disable button. I am using AngularJS 1.3.15 for this project.

**main.html**

```
<body>
<button ng-disabled="isItemDeleted" ng-init="isItemDeleted=true" 
class="btn btn-lg btn-primary create-txn-button" ng-click="submit()">Submit Transaction</button>
```

**deleteController.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',
function{};     
$scope.deleteItem = function(item) 
{
    $scope.isItemDeleted = false;
    var modalScope = $scope.$new(true);
    modalScope.message = 'Why would you like to delete this item?';
    modalScope.item = item;
    modalScope.transaction = $scope.transaction;
};
```

But, even after setting the `$scope.isItemDeleted` to false, the submit button is not enabled. I believe the issue is connecting to the controller. I have to connect my div tag to the controller. But if I do it, the entire page is changed. Any clue?

Update: `deleteItem()` function is getting called by Delete Button.

**DeleteButtonTabView.html**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<button ng-click="deleteItem(item)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Please find the link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1bnv9fr/

Comment: could you provide more code from delete button please ? Or make a plunker ?

Comment: @Korte I have added the Delete Button code.

Comment: Please include some more code of main.html as well.

Comment: @31piy Can you tell me, specificly, what are you looking for?

Comment: I need to see more lines around `<button ng-disabled="isItemDeleted"`.

Comment: @31piy that is all I have in it. Rest is plain HTML. It's actually a personal project I am working on right now.

Comment: created a plunker with your code - http://plnkr.co/edit/gC74K5apEDqj1ymo3B0N, but cannot reproduce mentioned issue, please update my plunker to show the problem

Comment: Are you sure deleteItem(item) is getting called? Can you give a console.log an d ensure?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. The code works fine, when I commented out the lines except `$scope.isItemDeleted = false;` of `$scope.deleteItem` method. Can you observe your console and ensure if there's not any error?

Comment: @Andriy I have updated the Plunker. Please check it.

Comment: @SreehariS deleteItem is getting called. I have a console.log to do the check.

Comment: @31piy I checked the console. There aren't any errors

Comment: @user2607744, my plunker is unchanged, please provide the forked one

Comment: @andriy please check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1bnv9fr/

Comment: sorry, your code is not running in jsfiddle, but you wrote 'Remember: Submit Transaction is in main.html view and Delete is in deleteItemView.html view', so their scopes are probably isolated and completely different. You need to make them share the same code or share state via service for example. Please create fully functional jsfiddle or plunker with different HTMLs, so I can check it and hopefully fix it

Comment: @user2607744 fixed your jsfiddle and it seems to work just fine, is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/38hywppL/

Comment: @Andriy I am sorry but I came to know where the problem is - my div/body is not connected to the controller. It is supposed to be "connected" to the `deleteController.js`